# how to write a query using "like" when i have to pass the variable, fetched from a different query in sql/plsql?

Tags: sql, plsql

```
key_ref like '%@SELECT 'PM_NO='||PM_NO||'^' FROM ifsapp.PM_ACTION_TAB@RP001 WHERE contract ='6070'@%'
```

Inside `like` there are `'` so it is not reading the whole code, what alternative can I use here ?

Comment: The expression on the right hand side of `like` is evaluated before the pattern matching starts, so I am not sure what you mean about a `'` character making anything 'not read the whole code'. Perhaps a complete worked example would help.

Comment: The string expression is not properly formed starting from `'%@SELECT 'PM_NO`

Answer (score 0):

key_ref like '%@SELECT PM_NO='||PM_NO||'^ FROM ifsapp.PM_ACTION_TAB@RP001 WHERE contract =''6070''@%'

Answer (score 0):

You must escape the `'` char by another preceding `'`. So for you it would be:

```
key_ref like '%@SELECT ''PM_NO=''||PM_NO
           ||''^'' FROM ifsapp.PM_ACTION_TAB@RP001 WHERE contract =''6070''@%'
```